# Triangle to draw a triangle on a swing high

Tags: pine-script

Hi I'm trying to draw a triangle every time there is a swing high. I define a swing high as when there are three candles where the first candle's high is lower than the second candle's high and the third candle's high is lower than the second candle's high.

```
//@version=4
study(title = "Swing High", overlay = true)
if(high[1] > high and high[2] < high[1])

    plotshape(bar_index[1], shape.triangleup)
```

Right now i'm getting the error "line 5: Cannot use 'plotshape' in local scope."

Answer (score 0):

Error message is clear. You cannot have that funciton in a local scope (if block etc.).

However, you can apply your condition directly in the `plotshape()` function like so:

```
//@version=4
study(title = "Swing High", overlay = true)

swing_high = (high[1] > high and high[2] < high[1])

plotshape(swing_high[1], style=shape.triangleup)
```

[image]

Comment: `//@version=5
indicator(title='Swing High', overlay=true)

plotshape(series=high[1] > high and high[2] < high[1], style=shape.triangleup)`


I tried doing it like this. But the problem now is that I want it to paint on the middle candle, not the current candle. Could you help in this regard?